# How to parse object which is sometimes Json object and sometimes json Array

Tags: android, parsing, gson

I working with API in which an object can an be array or it can be any object and I don't know in which scenario it will be object or array so i can't use different object base on some condition.

Unfortunately I've no access to API code so I can't do any changes there. Any trick that I've to do will be on client side.

So what is the best way to handle that scenario.

**Edit** : Response Example

```
.
.
  "ecf":"0",
            "place":{  },
            "mn":"1st Test",
            "teams":[  ],
            "past_ings":[  
               {  
                  "s":{  },
                  "d":{  
                     "a":{  
                        "t":{  
                           "i":"5221",
                           "a":"3",
                           "c":"not out",
                           "dt":null,
                           "fd":"0",
                           "bd":"0",
                           "cb":"no",
                           "b":"1",
                           "r":"0",
                           "sr":"0",
                           "four":"0",
                           "six":"0",
                           "name":"Umesh Yadav"
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
.
.
```

The object t can be array or it can be object.

*Note : I'm using Gson for parsing and using Retrofit in my network layer.*

Answer (score 2):

```
Object response = json.get("response")
if (response instanceof JSONArray) {
  // It's an array, cast it as a JSONArray to use it.
} else {
  // It's an object, cast it as a JSONObject to use it.
}
```

Comment: I'm not doing manual parsion. I'm using Gson and retrofit in my network layer

Comment: In that case, can't you just tell Retrofit to expect an Object and then do the check? I'm not that familiar with Retrofit, I'll read up on it.

Answer (score 0):

Just define this is Object when parse json by Gson in Java.
After that you have manual if then object is array or object.